# Can I use temporary value in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Can I write somthing like this in query?

```
SELECT X AS Y WHERE Y = SOMETHING
```

Or I can't use Y in WHERE in same query?

Comment: Are you trying to hide column names of a table? Maybe you'd find a `VIEW` as being more useful.

Comment: I have first static part of query in one class, and second part of query in second class where query is using. 
SELECT X AS Y is in first part, 
WHERE Y = SOMETHING should be in second part.
But I don't know in second part what is X (which string is X) becoues that are changeble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to refer to by original column name (not the alias):

```
SELECT X AS Y 
FROM myTable
WHERE X = SOMETHING
```

If you want to refer to the alias, create a derived table and SELECT  from it.

```
SELECT Y FROM
(SELECT X AS Y 
FROM myTable) tmp
WHERE Y = SOMETHING
```

Depending upon what you are trying to achieve a [VIEW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) might be appropriate.

Comment: Thank you! I will use that.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use an alias in a `where` clause.

But in other clauses like `group by`  and `having`.

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/808479/4)